# DependencyProperty Binding to a programmatically created ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml, data-binding

Im new to WPF / Silverlight so its hard for me to describe what i try to do. Maybe that is the reason i could not find a answer on Stackoverflow and Google.

I try to bind to a `DependyProperty` programmatically.

```
public static DependencyProperty MyDependencyProperty
        = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                            "...", 
                            typeof(...),
                            typeof(...),
                            new PropertyMetadata(...)
                      );
```

```xml
xmlns:MyXMLNS="clr-namespace:...."

<ListBox MyXMLNS:MyClass.MyDependencyProperty="...">
    // ....
</ListBox>
```

This already works as expected.

How can i get this done programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format in code is always the same and just a non-verbatim translation if you know how the XAML is handled.

```
<ListBox local:Attached.Test="{Binding PathToProperty)"/>
```

```
var binding = new Binding("PathToProperty");
listBox.SetBinding(Attached.TestProperty, binding);
```

If you set other properties on the binding like ElementName you should set those before [`SetBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598273.aspx). (This `SetBinding` method is just for convenience (if you only set the `Binding.Path` there even is [another one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598270.aspx)), for non-FrameworkElements you need [`BindingOperations.SetBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.setbinding.aspx))